# Voice Call Action on Glass does not dial to the set Contact Phone Number

Tags: java, google-mirror-api, google-glass

We are creating a TimelineItem with a Voice Call MenuItem. We create a new Contact object and dynamically set the phone number and set the Contact object onto the created TimelineItem. The action fires off as expected, but Glass dials out to a completely different and invalid phone number.

```
    List<MenuItem> menuItemList = new ArrayList<MenuItem>();
    menuItemList.add(new MenuItem().setAction("VOICE_CALL"));

    // set phone number to call
    TimelineItem callTimeline = new TimelineItem();
    callTimeline.setCreator(new Contact().setPhoneNumber(property.getMainPhoneNumber()));
    callTimeline.setMenuItems(menuItemList);
```

Is this the appropriate way to set a phone number to a TimelineItem?

Comment: Could you provide the format of the phone number?

Comment: The format we are using is: "+12035555555"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me, I did it on C#.Net but hope it helps you too.

Create the contact

```
Contact Amalan = new Contact();
        Amalan.PhoneNumber = "+940713429751";
```

create the time line and set creator as the the contact object we created

```
TimelineItem contactNumber = new TimelineItem()
     {

         Text = "Call Amalan",
         BundleId = "8081",

         Creator = Amalan,
         MenuItems = new List<MenuItem>() {  
                                         new MenuItem() {Action = "VOICE_CALL"},
                                         new MenuItem() {Action = "DELETE"}},
         Notification = new NotificationConfig() { Level = "DEFAULT" },

     };
```

Now insert the card into time line

```
controller.Service.Timeline.Insert(contactNumber).Fetch();
```

That's it, It worked fine for me. Don't forget your phone must be paired with your glass

Comment: Our error was not the phone number format, but rather in the way we initialized our MenuItems. Thank you for pointing out the painfully obvious :-). Thanks @AmalanDhananjayan!